# Display ads with Flurry in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, banner, flurry, iad

I am trying to display an ad banner using the Flurry library.

I import "Flurry.h", "FlurryAds.h" and "FlurryAdDelegate.h"

AppDelegate.m:

> [Flurry startSession:@"My application id"];

rootview Class:

> [FlurryAds setAdDelegate:self];
>       [FlurryAds fetchAndDisplayAdForSpace:@"BANNER_MAIN_VIEW" view:self.view size:BANNER_TOP];

However, I am getting the following error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
>         -[FlurryVideoPlayer playVideo:view:ad:] in libFlurryAds.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
>         -[FlurryVideoPlayer moviePreloadDidFinish:] in libFlurryAds.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)

What is wrong with this code? Am I missing something? Does anyone have a demonstration on how to use Flurry to display ad banners?

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis..Thanks for nice editing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the MediaPlayer Framework under the Link Binary with Library in Build Phases tab of Project's Settings

Comment: It's working man..Thanks !, Can you Please tell me why i need to add MediaPlayer Framework ? i mean i have including related frameworks like systemConfiguration and storeKit. +1 for you.

Comment: one more thing can i set frame for this ad banner ?